# Simulate drag option with pygames

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how I could keep printing 'test' only when my my left mousebutton is clicked AND is moving?  I am trying to simulate a sort of drag option. This is what I came up with:

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
screen.fill((250, 250, 250))
x = 10
y = 10
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (x,y, 100,100))
while True: # main game loop
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             sys.exit()
         if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
             if event.type == MOUSEMOTION: # This does not work
                 print 'test'
     pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you for any help or tips!

Comment: `This does not work` - What exactly isn't working? What do you expect and *how does the actual output differ*?

Comment: What I try to accomplish is;  everytime I move my mouse when I have my mousebutton pressed (like a drag),  'test' will be printed to the console.

Sorry it is hard for me to describe

Comment: I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but what is happening instead? Please be descriptive.

Comment: well, now it is not printing anything. So the mousemotion work. It works kind of  when I only use: if event.type == mousemotion, but then I there is no mousebutton down. I can't seem to connect the mousemotion and mousedown

Comment: What does `pygame.event.get()` return? (I'm unfamiliar with `pygame`) Is it a list of events? A generator? If you're unsure please `print pygame.event.get()` before you being your iteration. Then please give me an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

event.type can only be one thing at once so `event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.type == MOUSEMOTION` will never be true.

What I would do is create a bool that is true when the mouse button has been pressed

```
mousebeingpressed = False
While True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousebeingpressed = True
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousebeingpressed = False
        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and mousebeingpressed == True:
            #do stuff
```

Comment: I came here to write basically exactly this.  The Asker needs to rely on a mouse up / mouse down toggle rather than trying to capture two events at once.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and mousebeingpressed == True --> it seems this never gets true

Comment: I see what's happening...

I wrote the code ambiguously. `mousebeingpressed = False` needs to be outside of your `While True:`

I'll update the response to indicate this. Basically, it was just resetting `mousebeingpressed = False` with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to call [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) to check if a mouse button is pressed like

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == MOUSEMOTION and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]: 
         # do something
```

so you don't need to check for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`/`MOUSEBUTTONUP` and you don't need an extra variable.